# Is it possible to get Google+ to create one story from 2 people's camera roll?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

I love Google+’ Stories feature, where it takes camera photos you've uploaded and automatically infers when you go on holiday / have a trip away and presents it as a sort of slideshow.

Often though, I'm with one or more other people, who also have Google+. We're all taking photos which are automatically uploaded and we each get separate stories created, but I'd like to be able to combine all the photos to get one story for all of us.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best chance at this is to download the other person's photos and to re-upload them into your own space.

You can then re-generate the story and hope it will pick up the new pictures.

Comment: Thought that might be the case, it's a bit of a shame though as I'd imagine it's a *fairly* common scenario. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To re-generate a google+ photo story at any time on the desktop go to your google plus photos, select stories from the "More" menu, click the story. Then on the stories cover page you'll find a small menu. Select re-generate ("Geschichte neu erstellen"). You'll get the usual g+ notification when this has finished.